# Converting Data.Reify explicit sharing graph to AST with de Bruijn indices

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to recover sharing (in the [Type-Safe Observable Sharing in Haskell](http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/pub/Afp/CourseLiterature/Gill-09-TypeSafeReification.pdf) sense) for a simple AST, using `Data.Reify`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable, DeriveFunctor, DeriveTraversable, TypeFamilies #-}
module Sharing where

import Data.Foldable
import Data.Reify
import Data.Traversable

-- Original AST, without sharing. Expressed as a functor for ease of
-- use with Data.Reify.
data AstF f =
      LitF Int
    | AddF f f
    deriving (Foldable, Functor, Show, Traversable)

newtype Fix f = In { out :: f (Fix f) }

instance Traversable a => MuRef (Fix a) where
    type DeRef (Fix a) = a
    mapDeRef f = traverse f . out

type Ast' = Fix AstF

-- Final AST, with explicit sharing.
data Ast =
      Var Name
    | Let Ast Ast
    | Lit Int
    | Add Ast Ast
    deriving Show

type Name = Int  -- de Bruijn index

-- Recover sharing and introduce Lets/Vars.
recoverSharing :: Ast' -> IO Ast
recoverSharing e = introduceLets `fmap` reifyGraph e
  where
    introduceLets :: Graph (DeRef Ast') -> Ast
    introduceLets = undefined  -- ???
```

I have the feeling that implementing `introduceLets` (which should introduce both `Let`s and `Var`s) ought to simple and short, but I don't have enough experience with de Bruijn indices to know if there's a standard way to do it. How would you convert the `Graph` representation into the `Ast` representation?

P.S. Note that this is a quite degenerate case, as `Ast'` doesn't actually have a binding constructor of its own; all bindings come from the sharing recovery.

P.P.S. Ideally we wouldn't introduce `Let`s for single use expressions (although if we do we can remove them using an inlining pass.)

Comment: `AstF` shouldn't be directly recursive - that's what `Fix` is for. Change the `AddF` case to `AddF f f`, otherwise you won't get any sharing recovered by `reifyGraph`. Also, what do you expect to happen if someone writes a recursive or mutually recursive expression? De Bruijn indicies can't represent that (I think). Finally, I don't think this is totally trivial because the list of bindings from `reifyGraph` don't come topologically sorted.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam fixed the `AstF` definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We'll divide this problem into 3 parts. The first part is to use the [data-reify library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-reify) to recover the graph of the `AstF`. The second part will create an abstract syntax tree with `Let` bindings represented with de Bruijn indices. Finally, we will remove all of the unnecessary let bindings.

These are all the toys we will use along the way. `StandaloneDeriving` and `UndecidableInstances` are only needed to provide `Eq` and `Show` instances for things like `Fix`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Foldable
import Data.Reify
import Data.Traversable
import qualified Data.List as List

import Data.IntMap ((!))
import qualified Data.IntMap as IntMap

import Prelude hiding (any)
```

#### Use data-reify

You have almost all of the pieces in place to use the data-reify library.

```
data AstF f =
      LitF Int
    | AddF f f
    deriving (Eq, Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)


newtype Fix f = In { out :: f (Fix f) }

deriving instance Eq (f (Fix f)) => Eq (Fix f)
deriving instance Show (f (Fix f)) => Show (Fix f)

instance Traversable a => MuRef (Fix a) where
    type DeRef (Fix a) = a
    mapDeRef f = traverse f . out
```

All that's missing is the call to `reifyGraph`. Let's try a small example

```
do
    let example = In (AddF (In (AddF (In (LitF 1)) (In (LitF 2)))) example)
    graph <- reifyGraph example
    print graph
```

This outputs

```
let [(1,AddF 2 1),(2,AddF 3 4),(4,LitF 2),(3,LitF 1)] in 1
```

`graph` has the type `Graph AstF`, and is constructed by the constructor `Graph [(Unique, AstF Unique)] Unique`. The first argument to the constructor is the list of nodes with their new unique keys. Each edge in the structure has been replaced with the new unique key of the node at the edge's head. The second argument to the constructor is the unique key of the node of the root of the tree.

#### Convert graph to Let representation

We will convert the `Graph` from data-reify into a de Bruijn indexed abstract syntax tree with `Let` bindings. We will represent the AST using the following type. This type doesn't need to know anything about the internal representation of the AST.

```
type Index = Int

-- This can be rewritten in terms of Fix and Functor composition
data Indexed f
    = Var Index
    | Let (Indexed f) (Indexed f)
    | Exp (f (Indexed f))

deriving instance Eq (f (Indexed f)) => Eq (Indexed f)
deriving instance Show (f (Indexed f)) => Show (Indexed f)
```

The `Index`es represent the number of `Let`s between where the variable is used and the `Let` where it was declared. You should read `Let a b` as `let (Var 0)=a in b`

Our strategy to convert the graph into an `Indexed` AST is to traverse the graph starting at the root node. At every node, we will introduce a `Let` binding for that node. For every edge we will check to see if the node it refers to is already in an introduced `Let` binding that is in scope. If it is, we will replace the edge with the variable for that `Let` binding. If it is not already introduced by a `Let` binding, we will traverse it. The only thing we need to know about the AST we are operating on is that it is a `Functor`.

```
index :: Functor f => Graph (DeRef (Fix f)) -> Indexed f
index (Graph edges root) = go [root]
    where
        go keys@(key:_) =
            Let (Exp (fmap lookup (map ! key))) (Var 0)
                where
                    lookup unique = 
                        case List.elemIndex unique keys of
                            Just n -> Var n
                            Nothing -> go (unique:keys)
        map = IntMap.fromList edges
```

We will define the following for convenience.

```
reifyLet :: Traversable f => Fix f -> IO (Indexed f)
reifyLet = fmap index . reifyGraph
```

We'll try the same example as before

```
do
    let example = In (AddF (In (AddF (In (LitF 1)) (In (LitF 2)))) example)
    lets <- reifyLet example
    print lets
```

This outputs

```
Let (Exp (AddF (Let (Exp (AddF (Let (Exp (LitF 1)) (Var 0)) (Let (Exp (LitF 2)) (Var 0)))) (Var 0)) (Var 0))) (Var 0)
```

We only had 1 `let` binding in `example` but this has 4 `Let`s. We will remove the unnecessary `Let` binding in the next step.

#### Remove unnecessary `Let` bindings

To remove `Let` bindings that introduce unused variables, we need a notion of what a used variable is. We will define it for any `Foldable` AST.

```
used :: (Foldable f) => Index -> Indexed f -> Bool
used x (Var y) = x == y
used x (Let a b) = used (x+1) a || used (x+1) b
used x (Exp a)  = any (used x) a
```

When we remove a `Let` bindings, the number of intervening `Let` bindings, and thus the de Bruijn indices for variables, will change. We will need to be able to remove a variable from an `Indexed` AST

```
remove x :: (Functor f) => Index -> Indexed f -> Indexed f
remove x (Var y) =
    case y `compare` x of
        EQ -> error "Removed variable that's being used`
        LT -> Var y
        GT -> Var (y-1)
remove x (Let a b) = Let (remove (x+1) a) (remove (x+1) b)
remove x (Exp a) = Exp (fmap (remove x) a)
```

There are two ways a `Let` binding can introduce an unused variable. The variable can be completely unused, for example `let a = 1 in 2`, or it can be trivially used, as in `let a = 1 in a`. The first can be replaced by `2` and the second can be replaced by `1`. When we remove the `Let` binding, we also need to adjust all of the remaining variables in the AST with `remove`. Things that aren't `Let` don't introduce unused variables, and have nothing to replace.

```
removeUnusedLet :: (Functor f, Foldable f) => Indexed f -> Indexed f
removeUnusedLet (Let a b) =
    if (used 0 b) 
    then
        case b of
            Var 0 ->
                if (used 0 a)
                then (Let a b)
                else remove 0 a
            _     -> (Let a b)
    else remove 0 b
removeUnusedLet x = x
```

We'd like to be able to apply `removeUnusedLet` everywhere in the `Indexed` AST. We could use something more generic for this, but we'll just define for ourselves how to apply a function everywhere in an `Indexed` AST

```
mapIndexed :: (Functor f) => (Indexed f -> Indexed f) -> Indexed f -> Indexed f
mapIndexed f (Let a b) = Let (f a) (f b)
mapIndexed f (Exp a)   = Exp (fmap f a)
mapIndexed f x         = x

postMap :: (Functor f) => (Indexed f -> Indexed f) -> Indexed f -> Indexed f
postMap f = go
    where
        go = f . mapIndexed go
```

Then we can remove all the unused lets with

```
removeUnusedLets = postMap removeUnusedLet
```

We'll try our example again

```
do
    let example = In (AddF (In (AddF (In (LitF 1)) (In (LitF 2)))) example)
    lets <- reifyLet example
    let simplified = removeUnusedLets lets
    print simplified
```

This introduces only a single `Let`

```
   Let (Exp (AddF (Exp (AddF (Exp (LitF 1)) (Exp (LitF 2)))) (Var 0))) (Var 0)
```

#### Limitations

Mutually recursive definitions don't result in mutually recursive `Let` bindings. For example

```
do
    let
        left   =  In (AddF (In (LitF 1)) right       )
        right   = In (AddF left         (In (LitF 2)))
        example = In (AddF left          right       )
    lets <- reifyLet example
    let simplified = removeUnusedLets lets
    print simplified
```

Results in

```
Exp (AddF
    (Let (Exp (AddF
        (Exp (LitF 1))
        (Exp (AddF (Var 0) (Exp (LitF 2))))
    )) (Var 0))
    (Let (Exp (AddF
        (Exp (AddF (Exp (LitF 1)) (Var 0)))
        (Exp (LitF 2))
    )) (Var 0)))
```

I don't believe there is a mutually recursive representation for these in `Indexed` without using a negative `Index`.

Comment: There's a more sophisticated version of `removeUnusedLet` which counts the number of uses of the variable in the right hand side of the `Let`, and, if the count is 1 or fewer (and the variable is unused in the left hand side) replaces all the occurrences of the variable with the left hand side of the `Let`.